# Checking for existence of _id using and updating subdocument Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm currently trying to write a MongoDB backend for a puzzle website.  I'm fairly new to pymongo and I've been struggling to find a way to check for a unique key identifier and update a subdocument if it exits.  My layout is like this:

```
{
_id : Jack
"username": Jack
"puzzles": [
    {
        "name": puzName,
        "rank": rank,
        "date": puzDate,
        "Global Score": score,
        "Points": points
    }
],
"attempts": 1
}
```

If Jack already exists, I would like it to do this:

```
{
_id : Jack
"username": Jack
"puzzles": [
    {
        "name": puzName,
        "rank": rank,
        "date": puzDate,
        "Global Score": score,
        "Points": points
    }
    {
        "name": puzName2,
        "rank": rank,
        "date": puzDate,
        "Global Score": score,
        "Points": points
    }
],
"attempts": 2
}
```

To populate the fields, I'm taking fields from existing html and using Beautiful Soup.

```
cells = row('td')
rank = cells[0].string
name = cells[1].find_all('a')[1].find(text=True).strip()
score = row('td')[3].string
points = row('td')[4].string

puz_dict = {}
puz_dict['_id'] = name.encode('ascii','ignore')
puz_dict['username'] = name.encode('ascii','ignore')
puz_dict['puzzles'] = {'Puzzle Name': puzName, 'Rank': int(str(rank)), "Date": puzDate,'Global Score' : locale.atoi(str(score)), 'Points' : int(str(points)) }
puz_dict['attempts'] = 1

connection = MongoClient('localhost')
coll = connection['Puzzles']['Users']
if col.find({'_id' : puz_dict['_id']}).count() > 0:
     Print "Updating User"
     update stuff
else:    
     coll.insert(puz_dict)
```

As you can see I'm using the username as a way to uniquely identify the document.  So far so good.  Checking the database, user information populates properly.

Now I would like to check to see if a user already exists, and if they do, update the "puzzles" field to include that puzzle and increment the updates by 1. I thought this would work to check existence, but it doesn't seem to work and instead goes straight to insert:

```
if col.find({'_id' : puz_dict['_id']}).count() > 0:
     Print "Updating User"
     update stuff
```

Why is it not properly checking? How can I update the subdocument?

Comment: And what if the "user" doesn't exist? How about using the [`update_one()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) method?

Comment: so if the user (_id) doesn't exists in the collection, then the count should be 0.  If it's 0, then the insert() in the else will execute.  This will create a new _id and user in the collection.  I didn't include my update code because I haven't tested it.  I figure getting the find() to work properly first is more important

Comment: Does your `find()` query return any document? Also you have a typo in there. You are using `col.find()` instead of `coll.find()`, maybe that is the culprit. But frankly you don't need to use `coll.find().count()` you can just use the `update_one()` method with the `upsert` option set to `True` then check the value of `upserted_id` and `modified_count` and print a message accordingly.

Comment: You will need the [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) operator.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since you seem new to databases in general then it might strike you that the correct thing to do is not to "find" things then "update" and "save", but rather just to send an ["update"](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) request instead:

```
coll = connection['Puzzles']['Users']

# after each assignment

coll.update_one(
   { "_id": puz_dict["_id"] },
   {
       "$setOnInsert": { "username": puz_dict["username"] },
       "$push": { "puzzles": puz_dict["puzzles"] },
       "$inc": { "attempts": puz_dict["attempts"] }
   },
   upsert = True
)
```

So these "updates" work by looking for a document that matches the `_id` value and then considering the following actions:

- [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) contains content that will be added to an array field. So any new content will be "appended" to an array in the document named `"puzzles"`.
- [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) will look at the current value of `"attempts"` in the document and then "increment" that value by whatever value has been supplied as an argument there.
- [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) is special, and rather than making changes to every document that was matched, it instead only makes the supplied modifications where an `upsert` occurs.
- [`upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) is of course the final setting, which means that where the `_id` value was not matched, then a new document would be created instead with that `_id` value that was used to look for the document, and then any content that was mentioned in `$setOnInsert`.

Of course **every** matched document or created document would be subject to the other `$push` and `$inc` operations, so these will always be applied, either against existing content or by adding to the content already found in a matched document.

In the best case, when looping a data source it is better to commit such "writes" to the database in ["bulk"](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write), rather than just send every operation one at a time:

```
# import the UpdateOne bulk helper
from pymongo import UpdateOne

# Outside loop of writing sourcing data
operations = []

# Inside loop of sourcing data, add to the queue

operations.append(
    UpdateOne(
        { "_id": puz_dict["_id"] },
        {
            "$setOnInsert": { "username": puz_dict["username"] },
            "$push": { "puzzles": puz_dict["puzzles"] },
            "$inc": { "attempts": puz_dict["attempts"] }
        },
        upsert = True
    )    
)

# Only write to server 1 in 1000 and clear the queue
if ( len(operations) % 1000 == 0 ):
    coll.bulk_write(operations)
    operations = []

# Finish the loop

# Then only write again if there will still queued operations
# remaining on loop  completion

if ( len(operations) > 0 ):
    coll.bulk_write(operations)
```

That's basically how you handle it, by adding the operation for each line of detail processed as input and then writing several operations all at once ( ideally probably 1000 or less in accordance with driver ) rather than as idividual writes.

But at any rate, there is no need to "lookup" data as seperate requests, since this is what "updates" are particularly "upserts" are meant to handle. The atomic operations allow modification of data "in-place", so it is not necessary to read the document content before making changes.

---

Also note that "connections", such as those obtained by `MongoClient` should only every happen **once** in your application lifecycle. No matter what your application is actually doing, that connection should be available and persist throughout the life of that application until it runs to completion or otherwise termininates.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response!  I took on this project from someone else, and frankly, I was a bit clueless.  I read through a lot of documentation and examples, but it's always easier when someone directly addresses a problem!